# Software derived from LGPL library

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl

In my project I've used a library marked with the LGPL license as a reference example to developed my own library which is completely different but it works roughly in the same way.

Now I would like to sell my project which clearly links my own library and not the original one.

Is there any limitation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We cannot possibly answer this.

The crucial question is "Is your code a derived work of their code?" Since you started out with their code, it might very well be, even if no line remained unchanged. Basically, you did the exact opposite of a clean-room implementation.

But on the other hand, a clean-room implementation is generally considered a *sufficient* criterion for independent invention, not a *necessary* one. Therefore the case depends on more detail than you're giving here.

Comment: Well, in the very first release of my tool I'm planning to use a derived version of the original library, but in the next future I'll use my own library which source code is completely different.